# Is there a statistical profiler for python? If not, how could I go about writing one?

Tags: python, profile, stochastic

I would need to run a python script for some random amount of time, pause it, get a stack traceback, and unpause it. I've googled around for a way to do this, but I see no obvious solution.

Comment: What has this to to with profiling? What is the particular problem?

Comment: @RestRiciko: I'm not sure what your question is. I'm trying to find or write a stochastic profiler for python.

Comment: I think you invented the term "stochastic profiler". There is nothing like that - neither for Python nor for any other language. Inserting random breakpoints in your application is unlikely a problem to program *yourself*. Doing some measurements using the time module or what is straight forward including geting tracebacks. To bring it to the point: pretty vague and weird question.

Comment: @shino: I can't help but wonder what you'd actually use a random 'profiler' for? If you give us a bit more background, maybe we could help you solve whatever the root problem you're trying to solve... ?

Comment: Although it doesn't use the term "stochastic", [this answer to a C++-specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux#answer-378024) provides some pretty convincing advocacy for the described method of profiling.  It's currently at 167 upvotes.

Comment: I believe the OP means "statistical profiler" (as opposed to a "tracing profiler"). They're the two main profiling methods - either you stop the process periodically and gather statistics on what it is doing when you stop it, or else you trace everything the process is doing. The latter is more accurate, but also typically *much* slower due to the tracing overhead.

Comment: More info on the different kinds of profiler: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29#Methods_of_data_gathering

Comment: ncoghlan is correct; I do mean statistical profiler. I've looked into embedding python into a C program, and am trying to figure out if it is possible to pause it at random, or maybe run it for a specified number of bytecode operations.

Comment: Since the title changed, I'm guessing you figured it out :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's the [`statprof` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/statprof/)

`pip install statprof` (or `easy_install statprof`), then to use:

```
import statprof

statprof.start()
try:
    my_questionable_function()
finally:
    statprof.stop()
    statprof.display()
```

There's a bit of background on the module from [this blog post](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2012/04/09/reannouncing-statprof-a-statistical-profiler-for-python/):

> Why would this matter, though? Python already has two built-in profilers: lsprof and the long-deprecated hotshot. The trouble with lsprof is that it only tracks function calls. If you have a few hot loops within a function, lsprof is nearly worthless for figuring out which ones are actually important.
>
> A few days ago, I found myself in exactly the situation in which lsprof fails: it was telling me that I had a hot function, but the function was unfamiliar to me, and long enough that it wasn’t immediately obvious where the problem was.
>
> After a bit of begging on Twitter and Google+, someone pointed me at statprof. But there was a problem: although it was doing statistical sampling (yay!), it was only tracking the first line of a function when sampling (wtf!?). So I fixed that, spiffed up the documentation, and now it’s both usable and not misleading. Here’s an example of its output, locating the offending line in that hot function more accurately:
>
> ```
>   %   cumulative      self          
>  time    seconds   seconds  name    
>  68.75      0.14      0.14  scmutil.py:546:revrange
>   6.25      0.01      0.01  cmdutil.py:1006:walkchangerevs
>   6.25      0.01      0.01  revlog.py:241:__init__
>   [...blah blah blah...]
>   0.00      0.01      0.00  util.py:237:__get__
> ---
> Sample count: 16
> Total time: 0.200000 seconds
> ```
>
> I have uploaded statprof to the Python package index, so it’s almost trivial to install: "easy_install statprof" and you’re up and running.
>
> Since [the code is up on github](https://github.com/bos/statprof.py), please feel welcome to contribute bug reports and improvements. Enjoy!

Comment: Outstanding. I've wanted this for quite a while.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of a <s>couple of</s> few ways to do this:

- Rather than trying to get a stack trace while the program is running, just fire an interrupt at it, and parse the output.  You could do this with a shell script or with another python script that invokes your app as a subprocess.  The basic idea is explained and rather thoroughly defended in [this answer to a C++-specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux#answer-378024).

  - Actually, rather than having to parse the output, you could register a postmortem routine (using [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook)) that logs the stack trace.  Unfortunately, Python doesn't have any way to continue from the point at which an exception occurred, so you can't resume execution after logging.
- In order to actually get a stack trace from a running program, you <s>will</s> may have to hack the implementation.  So if you really want to do that, it may be worth your time to check out [pypy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/), a Python implementation written mostly in Python.  I've no idea how convenient it would be to do this in pypy.  I'm guessing that it wouldn't be particularly convenient, since it would involve introducing a hook into basically every instruction, which would I think be prohibitively inefficient.  Also, I don't think there will be much advantage over the first option, unless it takes a very long time to reach the state where you want to start doing stack traces.
- There exists a [set of macros](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) for the `gdb` debugger intended to facilitate debugging Python itself.  gdb can attach to an external process (in this case the instance of python which is executing your application) and do, well, pretty much anything with it.  It seems that the macro `pystack` will get you a backtrace of the Python stack at the current point of execution.  I think it would be pretty easy to automate this procedure, since you can (at worst) just feed text into `gdb` using `expect` or whatever.

Comment: Your second point is interesting. [rpdb2](http://winpdb.org/) (included with Winpdb) allows for pausing Python programs mid-execution. It may be possible to automate pausing the program through rpdb2, dumping the stack, and resuming execution.

Answer (score 3):

Python already contains everything you need to do what you described, no need to hack the interpreter.

You just have to use the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) module in conjunction with the [`sys._current_frames()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._current_frames) function. All you need is a way to dump the tracebacks you need at the frequency you want, for example using UNIX signals, or another thread.

To jump-start your code, you can do exactly what is done in [this commit](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/commit/16796274463f21327e1b7bb3831b39eb671460af):

1. Copy the [`threads.py`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/blob/16796274463f21327e1b7bb3831b39eb671460af/src/Signals/threads.py) module from that commit, or at least the stack trace dumping function (ZPL license, very liberal):
2. Hook it up to a signal handler, say, [`SIGUSR1`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/commit/16796274463f21327e1b7bb3831b39eb671460af#diff-3ed3ff07d875340423ee15bea776bb6fR118)

Then you just need to run your code and "kill" it with SIGUSR1 as frequently as you need.

For the case where a single function of a single thread is "sampled" from time to time with the same technique, using another thread for timing, I suggest dissecting the code of [**Products.LongRequestLogger**](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Products.LongRequestLogger) and its tests (developed by yours truly, while under the employ of [Nexedi](http://www.nexedi.com/)):

Whether or not this is proper "statistical" profiling, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/1273938) by [Mike Dunlavey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23771/mike-dunlavey) referenced by [intuited](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192812/intuited) makes a compelling argument that this is a very powerful "performance debugging" technique, and I have personal experience that it really helps zoom in quickly on the real causes of performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

To implement an external statistical profiler for Python, you're going to need some general debugging tools that let you interrogate another process, as well as some Python specific tools to get a hold of the interpreter state.

That's not an easy problem in general, but you may want to try starting with GDB 7 and the associated CPython analysis tools.

Answer (score 2):

There is a cross-platform sampling(statistical) Python profiler written in C called [vmprof-python](https://github.com/vmprof/vmprof-python).
Developed by the members of PyPy team, it supports PyPy as well as CPython.
It works on Linux, Mac OSX, and Windows. It is written in C, thus has a very small overhead. 
It profiles Python code as well as native calls made from Python code.
Also, it has a very useful option to collect statistics about execution lines inside functions in addition to function names.
It can also profile memory usage (by tracing the heap size).

It can be called from the Python code via API or from the console.
There is a Web UI to view the profile dumps: [vmprof.com](http://vmprof.com), which is also [open sourced](https://github.com/vmprof/vmprof-server).

Also, some Python IDEs (for example PyCharm) have integration with it, allowing to run the profiler and see the results in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Seven years after the question was asked, there are now several good statistical profilers available for Python. In addition to vmprof, already mentioned by [Dmitry Trofimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429873/dmitry-trofimov) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005232/8657876) answer, there are also [vprof](https://github.com/nvdv/vprof) and [pyflame](https://github.com/uber/pyflame). All of them support [flame graphs](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) one way or another, giving you a nice overview of where the time was spent.

Comment: Meanwhile the Pyflame authors [abandoned their project](https://github.com/uber-archive/pyflame): 'This project is deprecated and not maintained. '

Answer (score 2):

[Austin](https://github.com/P403n1x87/austin) is a frame stack sampler for CPython that can be used to make statistical profilers for Python that require no instrumentation and introduce minimal overhead. The simplest thing to do is to pipe the output of Austin with FlameGraph. However, you can just grab Austin's output with a custom application to make your very own profiler that is targeted at precisely your needs.

This is a screenshot of Austin TUI, a terminal application that provides a top-like view of everything that is happening inside a running Python application.
[image: Austin TUI]

This is Web Austin, a web application that shows you a live flame graph of the collected samples. You can configure the address where to serve the application which then allows you to do *remote* profiling.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Python there is [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) to dump the stacktraces. The dumps can get analyzed by [speedscope](https://github.com/jlfwong/speedscope)

Source: [Guidelines](https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines#statistical-profiler)